# Parquet creation Conversion from pandas dataframe to pyarrow table not working for object dtype

Tags: pandas, hive, parquet

I want to create a parquet file from a csv file. For test purposes, I've below piece of code which reads a file and converts the same to pandas dataframe first and then to pyarrow table. This table is then stored on AWS S3 and would want to run hive query on the table.

Inputfile contents:

```
YEAR|WORD
2017|Word 1
2018|Word 2
```

Code:

```
dataFrame=pd.read_csv(inputFile, sep='|')
print(dataFrame)
print(dataFrame.dtypes)
print(dataFrame.columns)
dataFrame['C1'] = dataFrame['C1'].astype('str')
print(dataFrame.dtypes)
table=pa.Table.from_pandas(dataFrame)#,schema=pa.string())
pq.write_table(table, outputFile)
```

After writing to pyarrow table, I queried the parquet file to make sure the data is good to be stored in S3. However the results are weird:

```
+--------+--------------+
| YEAR  |     WORD     |
+--------+--------------+
| 2017   | [B@60716d4f  |
| 2018   | [B@36bf8f00  |
+--------+--------------+
```

Somehow the int values show fine, however the object/str value doesn't get converted fine.

Appreciate your help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: hi, would you mind opening an issue on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW and we can help debug there?

Comment: here is an arrow issue to track this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-785

Comment: Updated the JIRA with more details.

Answer (score 0):

This replicated fine for me for roundtripping. Please specify your platform & versions of `python`, `pandas` and `pyarrow`

On 3.6 / macox (also worked on 2.7)

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import pyarrow as pa

In [3]: pd.__version__
Out[3]: '0.19.2'

In [4]: pa.__version__
Out[4]: '0.2.0'

In [5]: data = """YEAR|WORD
   ...: 2017|Word 1
   ...: 2018|Word 2
   ...: """

In [6]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='|')

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   YEAR    WORD
0  2017  Word 1
1  2018  Word 2

In [8]: df.dtypes
Out[8]: 
YEAR     int64
WORD    object
dtype: object

In [9]: table=pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

In [10]: import pyarrow.parquet as pq

In [12]: pq.write_table(table, 'foo.pk')

In [13]: pq.read_table('foo.pk').to_pandas()
Out[13]: 
   YEAR    WORD
0  2017  Word 1
1  2018  Word 2

In [14]: pq.read_table('foo.pk').to_pandas().dtypes
Out[14]: 
YEAR     int64
WORD    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: using below versions:
>>> pd.__version__
u'0.19.2'
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> pa.__version__
'0.2.0'

Issue seems to be happening when querying through hive.

creating the hive table on top of parquet file like below:
%sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema_abc.parquet_table_name(
YEAR INT
, WORD STRING
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/folder/parquet_files/'

***Please note: parquet_files folder has the testFile.parquet file in it.